# Internationalization for RESTful Services

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, locale, spring-restcontroller

```java
@GetMapping(path="/internationalized")
public String internationalized(@RequestHeader(name="Accept-Language",required=false) Locale locale ){
    return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null,"Default Message", locale);
}
```

I have `messages.properties`, `messages_nl.properties` and `messages_fr.properties` in resources.

I am unable to display the default message whenever I am giving any other language as an input. Its displaying message from messages.properties file though I am giving Chinese locale.

Comment: Remove the `@RrequestHeader` annotation. Spring will use a `LocaleResolver` to detect the `Locale`, or just pass `null` as the `Locale`.  Also `messages.properties` **is** the default.

Comment: okay, so messages.properties is the default . Is there anyway to implement this method of MessageSource . String getMessage(String code, Nullable Object[] args, Nullable String defaultMessage, Locale locale); of MessageSource Interface so that the specific defaultMessage passed the arguments can be displayed.

Comment: The default message will only be displayed if there is also nothing in the properties file.